# Eliminate the ungroup... message from tidyverse package

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

When I run the following command I get an annoying message that says: `summarise() ungrouping output (override with .groups argument)`.

I was wondering how I can eliminate this message in my data below?

```
library(tidyverse)

hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')  
ave_cluster_n <- as_vector(hsb %>% dplyr::select(sch.id) %>% group_by(sch.id) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>%  ungroup() %>% dplyr::select(n))

# `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument) # How to eliminate this message
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can specify the `.groups` argument in `summarise` with different options if we want to avoid getting the message.  Also, to extract as a `vector`, in the tidyverse, there is `pull` to pull the column

```
library(dplyr)
hsb %>% 
    dplyr::select(sch.id) %>%
    group_by(sch.id) %>%
    summarise(n=n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    pull(n)
```

---

Or another option is to bypass the `group_by/summarise` altogether and use `count`

```
hsb %>%
   count(sch.id) %>%
   pull(n)
```

Or with `tally`

```
hsb %>%
   group_by(sch.id) %>% 
   tally()
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be managed as a pkg option:

```r
library(tidyverse)
options(dplyr.summarise.inform = FALSE)
```

... and you don't see those messages anymore